# qqx, shell and run yield different results since raku 2022.04 on macOS

Tags: raku

Has there been a change in raku 2022.04 which breaks `qqx`, `shell` and `run`?

The following command prints "ok" on raku 2022.03:

```
echo hi | raku -e 'sub MAIN() { for slurp() { shell <<echo ok>>; } }'
```

It won't print anything on raku 2022.04 and up.

When removing the MAIN function like so:

```
echo hi | raku -e 'for slurp() { shell <<echo ok>>; }'
```

the command prints "ok" on every version of raku up to 2023.06.

Comment: This feels like it might be a macOS security thing, 2022.07 (the version I have currently installed) running on Linux has `qqx` running just fine. I know Apple recently release some security updates to do with running executables this may be effecting it?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this on HEAD on MacOS 12.5: `% mkdir foo
% cd foo
% echo bar > bar
% echo baz > baz         
% raku -e 'my $out = qqx|ls -l|; say $out'
total 16
-rw-r--r--  1 liz  staff  4 Aug 19 13:51 bar
-rw-r--r--  1 liz  staff  4 Aug 19 13:52 baz`

Comment: I have been using rakubrew to go back one version at a time to find the latest version which ran the script ok. This is how I arrived at raku-2022.04. I can no longer reproduce the problem. Every single version does work. My sincere apologies for wasting your time!

Comment: @Scimon Proctor: In my case this seems unlikely as I have not updated macOS in the past weeks. Good point, though!

Comment: Hi @C.Ocoa Thank you for following up. Don't worry about the mistake -- we all make mistakes. I think the right thing to do now is to A) celebrate and B) close your Q. Do you have Close available to you (in the menu line below your Q)? For me I see links for Share Edit Follow Close Flag. If you don't see it, or prefer not to, I can do that for you. But I thought it polite to wait for you to do it if you can/want.

Comment: Hi @raiph! I only have Share, Edit, Delete and Flag available. I'd appreciate if you could close the question for me. Thank you!

Comment: Hi @C.Ocoa I clicked Close to register one vote to close. Now others with suitable privs will have to agree for it to go through.

Comment: Hi @raiph I have updated the question. The problem is reproducible for me given the script added to the question. I would appreciate if you could verify my claim. Thank you very much!

Comment: Hi @C.Ocoa  I've confirmed [your example code works for glot.io's v2022.02 Rakudo](https://glot.io/snippets/g993acx31g). I think the sensible thing to do next is for you to [click here to pop onto #raku-beginner IRC channel](https://kiwiirc.com/nextclient/irc.libera.chat/#raku-beginner), paste a link to this SO, and ask for confirmation there that it does not work with recent Rakudos. Provided there's someone around they'll get to the bottom of it with you. If no one is around, please periodically peek at [the logs](https://irclogs.raku.org/raku-beginner/live.html) and revisit when you can.

Comment: @raiph Thank you! I'll proceed as suggested and will post updates here.

Comment: The report sounds very believable – it could be that `slurp().lines` behaves differently now for stdin that is not fully flushed. However, I was not able to find any difference in behavior locally between 2022.03 and 2022.04. @C.Ocoa your question says that it “stops working”, can you provide both the expected and wrong output? Because the meaning of `slurp().lines` is a bit unclear to me – when working in a terminal, I think you'd need to hit Ctrl+d in order to close stdin.

Comment: The #1 issue remains to reproduce your results, which you quite rightly asked us to verify as a first step. I was only able to verify it worked, not that it didn't, and then there was no one on #raku-beginners, and I then gambled that there was a problem that wasn't just your system, so bisect was the thing to do. But, like I said, repro is now even more top priority. If you wish you can view .@Aleks-DanielJakimenko-A.'s attempts to reproduce (and demonstrate ways to use bisectable6); I made [a manual gist of the IRC session](https://gist.github.com/raiph/7cbbd4c46f5986d4094fde7c03f16dca).

Comment: @Aleks-DanielJakimenko-A and @raiph. Having setup a Linux and two macOS VMs I can now report that the problem is related to macOS. If called like this: `echo hi | ./test.raku` the script should print the contents of the home directory. On Linux it does so regardless of the Raku version installed. On macOS 11 and 12 with moar-2022.03 the script works as expected. With moar-2022.04 it returns (exit code 0) without printing anything. I'll be on #raku-beginner today. Maybe there we can discuss how to proceed.

Comment: For now I am at the end of my wits. I have created an issue at Github: https://github.com/MoarVM/MoarVM/issues/1720